# JUnit Test "Times Out" Despite Executing Quickly?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I've got a couple of test cases that JUnit is telling me time out in 10000ms when the whole test run only lasts a couple of seconds. Here's the output:

```
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.528 sec <<< FAILURE!
closeTest1(com.w2ogroup.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.HttpServerTransportTests)  Time elapsed: 1.654 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 10000 milliseconds

closeTest2(com.w2ogroup.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.HttpServerTransportTests)  Time elapsed: 0.672 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 50000 milliseconds


Results :

Tests in error:
  HttpServerTransportTests »  test timed out after 10000 milliseconds
  HttpServerTransportTests »  test timed out after 50000 milliseconds

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.383s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jun 09 19:00:09 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/129M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems unlikely that my tests have timed out by taking more than 10 (or 50) seconds to run when the whole test run only lasted 4.3s. :)

Here's the surefire configuration from the POM I'm using to run the tests:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <!--
      We always want to exclude provided deps. I'm not sure why this
      isn't the default.
    -->
    <classpathDependencyScopeExclude>provided</classpathDependencyScopeExclude>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*Tests.*</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts about why this could be happening?

**EDIT**: Here's some more information, as requested below.

Here is the output of one of the tests. I'm building a simple transport mechanism, so I'm building unit tests that close streams and interrupt NIO threads to make them quit, which is why there are all those (expected) IO-type `Exception`s.

```
Running com.siggroup.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.HttpServerTransportTests
2013-06-10 08:32:53.195:INFO:oejs.Server:Thread-0: jetty-9.0.3.v20130506
Jun 10, 2013 8:32:53 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 12:47 PM'
2013-06-10 08:32:53.925:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Thread-0: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@30db7df3{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2013-06-10 08:32:54.136:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-0: Started ServerConnector@4584e5a8{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input$1: SelectChannelEndPoint@329ecdd9{/127.0.0.1:58667<r-l>/127.0.0.1:8080,o=true,is=false,os=false,fi=FillInterest@32f4dc3$
EOF
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input.blockForContent(HttpConnection.java:588)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:130)
       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read0(StreamDecoder.java:126)
       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:112)
       at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:168)
       at com.siggroup.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.WorkerTrackingDelegatingReader$2.work(WorkerTrackingDelegatingReader.java:64)
       at com.siggroup.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.WorkerTrackingDelegatingReader$2.work(WorkerTrackingDelegatingReader.java:1)
       at com.siggroup.analytics.commons.concurrent.Scope.work(Scope.java:49)
       at com.siggroup.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.WorkerTrackingDelegatingReader.read(WorkerTrackingDelegatingReader.java:60)
       at java.io.FilterReader.read(FilterReader.java:65)
       at java.io.PushbackReader.read(PushbackReader.java:90)
       at com.siggroup.sibyl.transport.impl.readerwriter.ReaderWriterTransportReaderThread.readPacket(ReaderWriterTransportReaderThread.java:32)
       at com.siggroup.sibyl.transport.impl.queued.QueuedTransportReaderThread.run(QueuedTransportReaderThread.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:996)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
       at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:317)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingCallback.block(BlockingCallback.java:96)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input.blockForContent(HttpConnection.java:559)
       ... 15 more
2013-06-10 08:32:54.958:WARN:oejs.HttpConnection:qtp557611759-26: HttpConnection@6a341611{FILLING_BLOCKED},g=HttpGenerator{s=END},p=HttpParser{s=CHUNKED_CONTENT,1 of$
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already Blocked
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection.block(AbstractConnection.java:233)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.access$400(HttpConnection.java:50)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input.blockForContent(HttpConnection.java:557)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.consumeAll(HttpInput.java:282)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.completed(HttpConnection.java:460)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:225)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
java.io.EOFException
       at com.siggroup.sibyl.transport.impl.readerwriter.ReaderWriterTransportReaderThread.readPacket(ReaderWriterTransportReaderThread.java:36)
       at com.siggroup.sibyl.transport.impl.queued.QueuedTransportReaderThread.run(QueuedTransportReaderThread.java:21)
```

The tests are run with `@Test(timeout=/* number */)`. Here's the signature of one of the test cases:

```
@Test(timeout = 10000)
public void closeTest1() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    /* Test goes here */
}
```

**EDIT**: Here is the entire contents of the surefire log:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.w2ogroup.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.HttpServerTransportTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.136 sec <<< FAILURE!
closeTest1(com.w2ogroup.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.HttpServerTransportTests)  Time elapsed: 2.218 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 10000 milliseconds

closeTest2(com.w2ogroup.analytics.sibyl.transport.impl.http.server.HttpServerTransportTests)  Time elapsed: 0.661 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 50000 milliseconds
```

**EDIT**: For posterity, @MatthewFarwell's answer below is correct, as indicated. I found that JUnit 4.12-SNAPSHOT was not available in Maven Central, so rather than set up more repositories and have a dependency on a SNAPSHOT artifact, I simply wrapped my test case in a `try`/`catch` for `InterruptedException`s, which kept the test case from propagating the `InterruptedException`, which fixed the problem.

Comment: Show us the stacktraces ...

Comment: Interesting ... but I meant the stacktrace that includes the `java.lang.Exception`.  It should be in the surefire reports.

Comment: @StephenC derp. Updated the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an issue with JUnit. In fact, the 'test timed out' message appears if there is an `InterruptedException`:

```
public class FooTest {
  @Test(timeout = 10000)
  public void timeoutTest() throws Exception {
    throw new InterruptedException("hello");
  }
}
```

results in:

```
java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

which is confusing to say the least. This happens even if you use the [Timeout Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/Timeout.java). So, in your example, you are throwing an `InterruptedException`

```
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:996)
   ...
```

and this is causing the false timeout exception.

This is a bug in 4.11 (and previous), but it does work correctly in 4.12-SNAPSHOT, it produces:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: hello
  at xxx.xxx.xxx.FooTest.timeoutTest(FooTest.java:13)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  ...
```

So, I would try out 4.12-SNAPSHOT, and if that works, you can either continue to use it (with your own private copy), or copy the new [Timeout](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/Timeout.java) rule & [FailOnTimeout](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/statements/FailOnTimeout.java) class into your code.

Then, when 4.12 comes out, you can revert. No idea when that will be btw.

Comment: Related things still plague JUnit 5.10. Alas.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have by any change a timeout defined for theses tests?

```
@Test (timeout=10000)
```

or

```
 @Rule
  public Timeout globalTimeout= new Timeout(10);
```

Comment: Good question. I'm using `@Test(timeout=10000)`. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit detects a test that has timed out by [catching a `TimeoutException`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/30f2b16525dabb477373be9ed3e76bb98b200806/src/main/java/org/junit/internal/runners/MethodRoadie.java#L76). This will normally be caused by the test framework calling [`shutdownNow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) on the `ExecutorService` that's running the test.

Is it possible that one of your failing tests is throwing this exception itself, and JUnit is reporting it as a test timeout?

Comment: That's great information. +1. My code definitely doesn't throw a `TimeoutException`, and I don't think my test is either. I am closing streams and interrupting NIO threads, though; are you aware of any reason why those would throw a `TimeoutException`? I'll wrap my tests in a `try`/`catch` to test this hypothesis.

Comment: `TimeoutException` is used by `ExecutorService`, which is [heavily used](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/class-use/ExecutorService.html) by the `nio` classes. So I guess internally the `nio` classes are triggering the TimeoutException.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the the connection hangs

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input.blockForContent(HttpConnection.java:588)
```

And the test doesn't really ends after a couple of seconds.

Try focusing on the **HttpConnection** error (or add your code if you need further help)

See examples for this problem:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401962
- https://code.google.com/p/gitblit/issues/detail?id=164